# Read data form serial port on windows with php

Tags: php, serial-port

I want to read data in php using USB serial.
I am Using  Rs232 to USB cable. I have sartorius balance machine. now i want to read machine data using USB com port. and store in database.

I am trying to use https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial
I don't know how to detect which com port are using by machine.

```
<?php
include "php_serial.class.php";
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage("Hello !");
$read = $serial->readPort();
$serial->deviceClose();
$serial->confBaudRate(2400);

echo "<pre>".var_export($serial, true)."</pre>"; 
?>
```

This code goes in to infinite loop.

Regards
N

Comment: I tried that php class, too. But it wasn't very stable. Today I would suggest using the [dio extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php) provided wia pecl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Node js To read serial port and send output to PHP server.

```
var fs = require('fs')
, http = require('http')
, socketio = require('socket.io')
, com = require("serialport");

var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

// create the server
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
httpServer: http.createServer().listen(1337)
});

var serialPort = new com.SerialPort("COM4", {
baudrate: 1200,
dataBits: 7,
parity: 'none',
stopBits: 1,
parser: com.parsers.readline('\r\n')
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
        //console.log('Received Message: ' + data);
        fs.writeFile("data.txt", data, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
        connection.sendUTF(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="index.php?status=1">ON</a></h1>
    <h1> <a href="index.php?status=2">off</a></h1>

   <?php
    //calling php serial class 
    require_once 'php_serial.class.php';
    $serial=new phpSerial();
    $serial->deviceSet('/dev/ttyACM2');
    $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->confFlowControl("none");
    $serial->deviceOpen();

    if($_GET['status']){
        $serial->sendMessage($_GET['status']);
        $read=$serial->readPort();

        var_dump($read);
        echo $read;
    }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is web page code html&php using php serial class

Answer (score -2):

```
 int led=3;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

int x=Serial.read();

if(x=='1'){
   digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    Serial.write(x);


}
if(x=='2'){
   digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    Serial.write(x);


  }


}
```

Comment: and this arduino code both of arduino and web page code works with me