# How to read serial port data using nodejs and send output to PHP server using rs232 cable?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, npm, serial-port

I need to read a serial port to get data using a RS232 cable, and want to send the output to a PHP server, but i found a way using node.js.
I searched a lot and also found [a solution in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619929/read-data-form-serial-port-on-windows-with-php) but it doesn't work for me.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux, I would try opening a file descriptor to /dev/your_serial_port. Your php script will probably need permissions (root) to read from this port.  You may have a tty group or something similar that allows read from this device.  In that case, I would recommend starting your script as root, and using `posix_setgid()` possibly with `posix_getgrnam()` to change your process group and not parade around as root.

```
$groupInfo = posix_getgrnam("tty");
if (! isset($groupInfo["gid"])) {
    // "Invalid worker group.
} else if (! posix_setgid($groupInfo["gid"])) {
    // Failed to change worker group. (privilege required)
}
```

I feel bad that you are probably on windows, so I dug around and I think you can open the file 'com1:' on windows and probably read serial data.  If that doesn't work, look for a cli program that can dump serial data to stdout and use something like proc_open to read data from it.  I have no windows computer to try anything ;(

Comment: thank you for your valuable response.. i have Rs232 cable and how can i use the above code to get data from the device (Accuref r-800)  and also may i know its is must need to create a socket...