# Read Serial Port on Windows

Tags: php, windows, serial-port

I am trying to use PHP to read weighing machine value(i.e., weight). Whenever I run the code below, it says

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded
```

I did something wrong, I don't know where it is?

The PHP Serial class offers a `readPort()` function, does not return (My assumption).

My PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Works with php</h1>
<p>First Page in PHP</p>

<?php
include 'PhpSerial.php';

    $serial = new phpSerial();
    $serial->deviceSet("COM3");
    $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->confFlowControl("none");
    $serial->deviceOpen();
    $serial->sendMessage("s");

    $read = $serial->readPort();
    echo ("Weight--->".$read );
    $serial->deviceClose();
?> 

<p>Sent Data to server </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the documentation of that function. Most likely it is blocking and won't return unteil the socket is closed or some timeout occurs.

Comment: thanks @arkascha. Sure I will check it now.

Comment: @Sathish Which version of windows are you using? Internally PhpSerial class uses [mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mode) command line utility when using windows so make sure it's there on your OS.

Comment: @Viney Hill. Am using windows 7.

Comment: Sometimes its working. But most of time it will throw the "<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded ". So what can I do..? really I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
require_once 'PhpSerial.php';
$serial=new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet('/dev/ttyACM2');
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceOpen();

if($_GET['status']){
    $serial->sendMessage($_GET['status']);
    $read=$serial->readPort();

    var_dump($read);
    echo $read;
}
```

Comment: may be you should follow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619929/read-data-form-serial-port-on-windows-with-php